# How to compare score differences across time using unpaired data?

Tags: group-differences, pre-post-comparison, control-group

An anonymous school climate survey was administered to students in 10 schools in 2017. We have student-level data from that survey, which includes each student's overall satisfaction score (scale of 0 to 100) and the school in which the student was enrolled.

Five of the schools then implemented a behavioral intervention program for the next three years and then another anonymous school climate survey was administered to students in all 10 schools in 2020. We want to know if student satisfaction scores improved more in the five schools implementing the behavioral intervention program than in the five "control" schools. Unfortunately, because the surveys were anonymous and no identifying information was collected for the students, we do not have the ability to pair the "pre" (2017) and "post" (2020) data.

What statistical test could we use to determine whether improvements in student satisfaction scores were greater for the "treatment" vs. "control" schools? We have contemplated repeated-measures ANOVA, regression, etc. but nothing seems "quite right" due to the unpaired nature of the scores. With a single group, we could have considered an independent samples t-test comparing the pre and post scores, but aren't sure what to do with two groups (not to mention multiple schools in each group). Should we be considering hierarchical or multi-level modeling approaches, or perhaps propensity scores? Any guidance on how we could execute a statistical test of the score differences across time would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!